# InstaPy: Any idea why interact_by_URL doesn't comment the provided URL?

Tags: python-3.x, instapy

I am new to Python, as well as new to InstaPy. I have configured a custom script to comment posts by provided URLs, but unfortunately, when the InstaPy running, it visiting the posts and doesn't comment them.

My code is the following:

```
# imports
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run
from instapy import set_workspace

# set workspace folder at the desired location (default is at your home folder)
set_workspace(path=None)

comments_list = ["comment #1", "comment #2", "... comment #X"]
accounts = [
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/1/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/2/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/3/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/.../",
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/X/",
]

# get an InstaPy session!
session = InstaPy(username="my_username", password="my_password")

with smart_run(session):
    # preparation
    session.set_do_follow(enabled=False)
    session.set_do_like(enabled=False)
    session.set_do_comment(enabled=True, percentage=100)
    session.set_comments(comments_list)
    session.set_user_interact(amount=1, randomize=True, percentage=15)

    # activity
    session.interact_by_URL(urls=accounts, randomize=True)
```

Do I have any wrong configuration? Do you see anything I have in wrong?

Otherwise, do you know any other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: do you fix this? same issue here